# Security issues installing nodejs

Tags: node.js, devops, admin

I used different versions of nodejs for years and never had the problems, but now I got one. So I had to uninstall some nodejs version and then I've tried to install the latest stable one and after that, out of sudden I got:

- the rights to the nodejs folder are assigned to SYSTEM (not sure whether previously it was the same, but previously I had no problems deleting the folder, uninstalling it, etc. Now I do! I have to change the permissions before deleting it although I am logged as a user who has admin rights)
- most weird thing: if I type npm or ng I get error message: access denied! Even if I run cmd as admin! Never had such the problem before! I googled, the only thing I found suggested to kill nodejs process...well, there is no nodejs process running, at least Task Scheduler does not show it.
  Please advise.

Comment: Have you used `fs.chmod()` method?

Comment: I have windows os